# With Excel-DNA, how can an unspecified argument in an Excel add-in function call be distinguished from a missing one?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-dna

This question is about Excel-DNA's interpretation of calls to add-in functions within Excel.

In Excel, **unspecified** and **missing** arguments are not the same. This can be seen with the `IF` function (which has two required parameters followed by one optional parameter):

`=IF()` - this is invalid

`=IF(,)` - returns FALSE

`=IF(,,)` - returns 0

I'm using the `ExcelIntegration.RegisterDelegates()` method to register add-in functions within Excel, registering functions like this:

```
Delegate del = new Func<object, object, object, object>((a, b, c) => a.ToString() + " " + b.ToString() + " " + c.ToString());

var fnAttr = new ExcelFunctionAttribute { Name = "TestFunc", Category = "ExcelDnaTest", Description = "Test function", IsHidden = false };

var args = new List<object>();
args.Add(new ExcelArgumentAttribute { Name = "Arg1", Description = "First argument", AllowReference = true });
args.Add(new ExcelArgumentAttribute { Name = "Arg2", Description = "Second argument", AllowReference = true });
args.Add(new ExcelArgumentAttribute { Name = "Arg3", Description = "Third argument", AllowReference = true });

ExcelIntegration.RegisterDelegates(new List<Delegate> { del }, new List<object> { fnAttr }, new List<List<object>> { args });
```

This works as expected when all arguments are supplied:

`=TestFunc("A", "B", "C")` - returns "A B C"

However, the result for no arguments (i.e. three **unspecified** arguments) is the same as when either two or three **missing** arguments are provided (I don't know a way to supply a single **missing** argument):

`=TestFunc()`

`=TestFunc(,)`

`=TestFunc(,,)`

All of these return:

"ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelMissing ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelMissing ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelMissing"

For add-in functions analogous to Excel's `IF` function, these three formulas represent different function calls, but I can't find a way to tell them apart - Excel-DNA seems to supply its `Missing` value both for **unspecified** and **missing** arguments.

**Q: Using Excel-DNA, how can I distinguish between the three calls to `TestFunc()` above?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't distinguish these cases in a user-defined function.

I don't believe the Excel C API (which Excel-DNA uses to implement the Excel -> .NET UDF interface) allows any UDF to see this distinction - there is no such concept as an 'unspecified' parameter in the C API - the XLOPER type in both of your cases is passed as `xltypeMissing`.